# Entity Framework eager includes for two single grandchildren

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I need to include grandchildren with my EntityFramework query (4.1), where the grandchildren are single leaves off the child, as follows:

> Schedule has one Route,
>   Route has one FromAirport and one ToAirport

I have tried the following:

```
.Include(x => x.Route.FromAirport).Include(x => x.Route.ToAirport)
```

But it produces a sql query like the following:

```
FROM       [dbo].[Schedule] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Route] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RouteId] = [Extent2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Route] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[RouteId] = [Extent3].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Airport] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[FromAirportId] = [Extent4].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Airport] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[ToAirportId] = [Extent5].[Id]
```

Route is of course being joined twice.  I can live with this as long as EF is binding to the entity models correctly.

Is there a better way of specifying the includes?

Comment: Try to query Routes and include from, to and schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Include(x => x.Route.FromAirport).Include(x => x.Route.ToAirport)
```

> Is there a better way of specifying the includes?

No, there is no better way using EF and not specifying your own query.

You obviously are aware of what the SQL statement looks like, but if you ran that query in SMSS and turned on the Execution Plan, you'll most likely see that it doesn't actually join twice (since the where statement is the same).  Unless you are having actual performance problems I would recommend not trying to review what EF is doing.  Additionally, since SQL Server has its own optimize engine, unless you check the Execution Plan, there is no telling what is actually going to happen.